# Can't open VS Code on Kali Linux as super user or root

Tags: kali-linux, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code on Kali Linux and when I tried opening it with the `code` command, this message would appear:

> You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument.

I tried this command:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
```

but that did not work either.

Comment: Tilde (`~`) is not expanded in quotes. You probably want to use `$HOME` in place of `~`.

Comment: "_I installed vs code on kali linux_" why would you want to do that? Kali is not a general purpose distribution

Comment: Doing "normal" work as root is indeed not recommended. (1) Make a non-root user, and use VS Code as normal user. (2)Kali Linux is intended for penetration testing, and not for anything where you'd use VS Code. You can make things a lot easier for yourself by just using a different distro intended for this usage (and this distro will have all the hacking tools Kali has, though you need to install them).

Comment: You're using kali for something it is not meant for, and trying to do normal work as root. That is like shooting yourself in *both* feet at once.

Comment: You guys are wrong, programming and pentesting pretty much goes together no? you're correct in that it shouldn't be run as superuser unless you're writing malware and need to debug it with priviledges

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
code /directory-to-open --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox
```

Comment: This answer is useless without knowing the corresponding working directory.